# Chemical standard state symbol with achemso article

Tags: chemistry, units, achemso, chemstyle

I am completely new to LaTeX, but I know how to use the chemstyles package to generate the standard state plimsoll in a document that I am working on for, say, my students, etc. However, for generating an ACS article, the standard state symbol does not seem to work when I use the achemso package.

Example code:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemstyle}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

$$\Delta_\mathrm{rxn} G^\standardstate$$

\end{document}
```

Changing the documentclass to article fixes the issue. Is there a way to generate the standard state symbol simply with the achemso package?

Comment: Forget chemstyle. Chemmacros package is what you need. Have a look the manual and search standard state.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll dig through the manual for chemmacros now; I found chemstyles via google search but haven't looked at the other chem packages yet. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a clash between `achemso` and `chemstyle` packages. Since [ACS guidelines](https://pubs.acs.org/page/4authors/submission/tex.html) only strongly encourage to use `achemso`, the functionality of `chemstyle` ([which also hasn't been updated since 2013](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemstyle)) can be replicated by other means. Since ACS suggests to

> Avoid extensive use of \newcommand and \def

I'm not listing any methods of creating own symbol (see e.g. [How to draw a Plimsoll? on latex.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8517)).

#### Method 1. Use `\standardstate` from [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros)'s `symbols` module

[image: Plimsoll symbol with chemmacros package]

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules={all}}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\[\Delta_\mathrm{rxn}G^\standardstate\]

\end{document}
```

#### Method 2. Use `\minuso` from [`stmaryrd`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) package

[image: Plimsoll symbol with stmaryrd package]

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\[\Delta_\mathrm{rxn}G^\minuso\]

\end{document}
```

#### Method 3. Use `\stst` from [`plimsoll`](https://ctan.org/pkg/plimsoll) package

*Note:* aside from `\stst` macro which is probably the optimal choice for chemists and is a recommended way of typesetting **st**andard **st**ate symbol listed in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive?lang=en) (accessed 2021-05-22), package `plimsoll` offers options for sans serif version of “⦵” symbol (`sans`) and redefinition of `\circ` macro to display plimsoll symbol (`circ`).
If the symbol is used for a purpose different from denoting standard state, there is a more semantically correct `\plimsoll` macro (for use in math mode).

[image: Plimsoll symbol with plimsoll package]

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage{plimsoll}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\[\Delta_\mathrm{rxn}G\stst\]
    
\end{document}
```

Kudos to [Linear Christmas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/116907/linear-christmas) for the suggestion to include the package to this list!

#### Method 4. Use `xelatex` and [a Unicode font with a support for `⦵` glyph](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/29b5/fontsupport.htm)

*Note*: probably the least portable method and not recommended for ACS submissions. Requires to bundle extra font or make absolutely sure the font is installed on a target system, and uses a compiler different from `pdflatex`.

[image: Plimsoll symbol with Unicode]

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\title{A title}

\begin{document}

\[Δ_\mathrm{rxn}G^⦵\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Greetings, andselisk! If you wish, you may add information about the package [``plimsoll``](https://ctan.org/pkg/plimsoll). The usage is ``$G\stst$``, ``$c\stst$``, so no ``^`` required. ("stst" is for *standard state*). The package has additional and optional arguments ``sans`` and ``circ`` to change the standard state symbol appearance. For more information, see [documentation](https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/plimsoll/plimsoll.pdf). It is also in "[The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](https://bit.ly/2Siv6Ym)", May 5, 2021 version, page 126: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjAMu.png).

Comment: @LinearChristmas Thank you very much for the suggestion, gratefully accepted and edited in. Unfortunately, I missed this newer package and I failed to update the answer in time:(

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install a package just for the standard-state symbol, you can create a mock-up:

```
\newcommand\standardstate{{\circ\kern-0.495em-}}

$ \Delta G = \Delta G^{\standardstate} + RT\ln(Q) $
```

[image: Formula with Delta G-standard]

A disadvantage is that the `\kern-0.495em` may need a bit of tweaking depending on the font. This works computer modern 11pt. In computer modern 12pt, use `-0.47em`; in 10pt, use `-0.525em`.

Use this for reports that you will distribute as PDF. Journals probably won't like this in submissions.